# Closed form solution for an $\ell{1}$ optimization problem with a quadratic constraint and bounded variables

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem

$$
\min \lVert{x}\rVert_{1} \quad\text{s.t} \quad \lVert{y - Ax}\rVert_2 \leq \varepsilon \quad \text{and} \quad x \in [0,1]^n,
$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $y = A x_0 + e$ for some $x_0 \in [0,1]^n$ and $e \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is some bounded noise with $\lVert{e}\rVert_2 \leq \varepsilon$. Since $x \in [0,1]^n$, we can rewrite $\lVert{x}\rVert_{1}$ as $\mathbf{1}^{T}x$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the $n$-dimensional vector consistings of all ones. My question is if there is a closed-form solution to the above problem? Since this is a convex problem, every local minimizer is also a global minimizer. One way to check this is clearly the Karush–Kuhn–Tucker (KKT) conditions. My approach was to form the Langragian, given by
\begin{align*}
L(x,\lambda,\alpha) = \mathbf{1}^Tx + \mu^T g(x),
\end{align*}
where $g(x) = (g_0(x),g_1(x),\dots,g_n(x),g_{n+1}(x),\dots,g_{2n}(x))$ is the vector of the $2n + 1$ constraints given by
\begin{align*}
&g_0(x) = \lVert{y - Ax}\rVert_2 - \varepsilon \\
&g_1(x) = -x_1 \\
&\vdots  \\
&g_n(x) =-x_n \\
&g_{n+1}(x) = 1 - x_1 \\
&\vdots \\
&g_{2n}(x) = 1 - x_n,
\end{align*}
and $\mu = (\mu_0,\dots,\mu_{2n+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ is the appropiate multiplier. Now the KKT conditions are given by
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{x} L(x,\lambda,\alpha) &= \mathbf{1} + \mu_0 \nabla g_0(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\mu_i \nabla g_{i}(x) \qquad \text {(Stationarity)} \\
g_i(x) &\leq 0 \qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{(Primal feasibility)} \\
\mu & \geq 0 \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{(Dual feasibility)}\\
\mu^T g(x) &= 0 \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad\text{(Complementary slackness)}
\end{align*}

Can this help me, to find a closed solution for the above problem?

Comment: I doubt that a closed solution can be computed efficiently.

Comment: Even if we assume that A is invertible?

Comment: Yes, I don't think that it helps. The problem is the combinatoric structure within the KKT conditions. That is, for each component $i$ of the inequality constraints, you have to decide whether $\mu_i = 0$ or $g(x_i) = 0$. This means $2^n$ decisions. And I do not think that you can choose the right decision in an efficient way.